# A simple algebra problem.

Tags: number-theory

Let $a\neq 0$ and $t$ be rational numbers, where $a$ is fixed and $t$ is variable. Suppose that for any nonzero rational $t$,

$$a^{2}t^{2} + at \neq t^3$$

so that

$$a^{2}t^{2} + at = r(t)t^3$$

where $r(t) \neq 1$ is a function of $t$.

Now suppose that

$$a^{2}t^{2} + at = t^5$$

Since $t\neq 0$ ,this implies that

$$r(t)=t^2$$

Hence it follows that, any rational solution to

$$a^{2}t^{2} + at = t^5$$

Would also be a rational solution to

$$a^{2}t^{2} + at = t^3$$

which by our assumption, has no nonzero rational solutions. This would also imply that

$$a^{2}t^{2} + at = t^5$$

has no nonzero rational solutions ?

Comment: Sorry, i had assumed that the case $a=0$ is trivial. Indeed, $a\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The following does not prove or disprove the proposition per se, but merely points out the misstep in the posted (attempted) proof.

> Since $t\neq 0$ ,this implies that
>
> $$r(t)=t^2$$
>
> ***Hence it follows*** that, any rational solution to
>
> $$a^{2}t^{2} + at = t^5$$
>
> Would also be a rational solution to
>
> $$a^{2}t^{2} + at = t^3$$

***That*** step does *not* follow. What *does* follow is that any rational solution $u$ to $a^{2}u^{2} + a u = u^5$ would be a rational solution to $a^{2}t^{2} + a t = b t^3$ where $b=u^2 \in \mathbb{Q}$. The latter would only reduce to the original equation if $b=1$ which is not guaranteed (and indeed not possible, since $a^{2}u^{2} + a u = u^5$ never has $\pm 1$ as a root when $a \in \mathbb{Q}$).

---

P.S. The question is rather confusingly phrased. The following is equivalent, and easier to follow.

> Let $a \in \mathbb{Q}^* = \mathbb{Q} \setminus \{0\}$ be a fixed non-zero rational number. If the equation in $t$
>
> $$a^{2}t + a = t^2$$
>
> has no rational roots $t \in \mathbb{Q}^*$ then the equation
>
> $$a^{2}t + a = t^4$$
>
> has no such roots $t \in \mathbb{Q}^*$ either.